# Read an XML file uploaded with app

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am using Java, GWT and Eclipse.  I have a static XML file I want to parse to get certain data that will fill in list boxes and other info. How can I read the static XML file in both the server and client side of the code?  Where do I put the XML file?  Also, where can I put it if I only want the server to have access to it (since it contains sensitive data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it on a server side only, put it in the /war/WEB-INF directory, and you can read it directly in your server code.

You can use a DataResource if you need a file on the client side:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#DataResource

If you want this file accessible on the client side, put it in the /war directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you parse the file server-side using any good XML parser (for an example see [this tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)) and put the resulting data in POJOs. For the data that you need client-side, you can make an RPC call to the server to retrieve the POJOs previously populated. A good place to put the XML file to prevent it from being directly accessible is under the WEB-INF directory of your webapp.